# How to capture no of errors in deleting multiple files in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I am deleting a no of directories/files using the following command. Per my knowledge, if any of the directory/files has access or any other issues, it will be skipped and rest of the files will be deleted.

```
find $CDIR -mtime +7 -exec rm -rfv {} \;

RETURN_CODE_CLEANUP=$?
```

Now, I want to check how many errors occurred in mass deletion. I think, the `RETURN_CODE_CLANUP` will be non-zero for one or more errors. How can I capture no of errors in this method?

Comment: Note that you will want to quote `$CDIR` as `"$CDIR"`, and since you are also removing directories that has not had files deleted or added to them in a week, you will also want to use `-depth` (before `-mtime`) so that `find` itself don't try to walk into directories that it has just deleted.

Comment: My idea would be redirecting STDERR to a temporary file and later using `wc -l` on that file to determine the number of errors, although I can't tell how good this approach is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the exact number of errors that `rm` produces:

```sh
find "$CDIR" -depth -mtime +7 -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if ! rm -rfv "$pathname"; then
           count=$(( count + 1 ))
        fi
    done
    printf "This batch caused %d errors in rm\n" "$count"' sh {} +
```

This would do a depth-first search of `$CDIR` and its sub-directories and delete any file or directory with a modification timestamp more than a week ago.  The in-line shell script would be called for batches of found pathnames, and it iterates over each, trying to delete it using `rm`.  If a deletion fails, it counts it.  At the end of the in-line script, the number of fails for that batch is reported.

Note that this is a very unsafe way to do a cleanup, as *the whole directory structure rooted at `$CDIR` will be deleted if no file or directory in `$CDIR` itself has been added or removed in a weeks time*.  The same issue is true for each subdirectory of `$CDIR`.

You may instead want to delete only old *files*, and then remove *empty* directories separately:

```sh
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if ! rm -fv "$pathname"; then
           count=$(( count + 1 ))
        fi
    done
    printf "%d files in this batch could not be deleted\n" "$count"' sh {} +

find "$CDIR" -type d -empty -delete
```

(This assumes that you have a `find` implementation that supports `-empty` and `-delete`, and that you are ok with deleting empty directories, even if they were not emptied by the first `find` command)

As always when testing commands that does cleanups like these, run on *copies* of data, and keep your data backed up.

---

Another (simpler) approach is simply to delete the old files, then to count the number old things still present.  That number will be the number of times `rm` failed (although I'm using `-delete` here for brevity):

```sh
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -delete
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```

You may then want to clean up empty directories as well, as above.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda I will try these approaches today. The last one is simpler, but  am thinking, if the minutes are also counted in calculating -mtime +7, then, considering the time required to delete files and next -mtime +7, the files created 7days back in this time range may be wrongly counted in wc -l command.

Comment: @SrinivasaraoKotipatruni `-mtime +7` will match things that are have a modification timestamp 8 "24 hour periods" or more in the past. The modification timestamp will first be rounded up to the next full 24 period. I.e., it does not take minutes into account.  For minute precision, use `-mmin +10080` (there are 10080 minutes in a week).

Comment: Thank You. This helps me. In such case, I need to make sure my script would not run around 12AM if I go for this appraoch.